# Datagridview is blank - trying to populate from API service reference

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, service-reference

I have been all over the net today trying different things, but I am just missing the boat somehow. I am trying to populate a datagridview with data from a supplied api. However, when the code executes, no errors are thrown, but no information is displayed within the datagridview. You will also notice a listbox referenced. I am able to display values from the API within the listbox as expected, so I know I am just doing something wrong with the datagridview setup, but I just can't seem to pinpoint it. Thanks for any help!

```
  Dim frmTestCase As New Form1

    Dim dgv As New DataGridView

    dgv = frmTestCase.DataGridView1

    dgv.Columns.Add("ID", "ID")
    dgv.Columns.Add("Name", "Name")

    Dim i As Integer

    'Loop through test cases and get their data for datagrid
    For i = 0 To UBound(remoteTestCases) - 1
        Dim matchingTestCase = remoteTestCases(i)
        Dim testCaseID As String = CStr(matchingTestCase.TestCaseId.Value)
        Dim testCaseName As String = matchingTestCase.Name

        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = New DataGridViewRow

        row.CreateCells(dgv)

        row.Cells(0).Value = testCaseID
        row.Cells(1).Value = testCaseName

        dgv.Rows.Add(row)


        Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(testCaseID)

    Next
```

Comment: I think the way you're adding it is incorrect. Are you certain the id and Name are cells 0 & 1? You might want to reference the column names instead, although that might not be your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
Dim frmTestCase As New Form1
Dim dgv As New DataGridView
dgv = frmTestCase.DataGridView1
```

*appears* to be trying to shorten the reference to `dgv`.  But in so doing, it creates a new `Form1` instance and by extension a new `DataGridView1`.  You could well be populating a DGV on a form that is never shown.

One remedy would be to rename `DataGridView1` on this form (Me) to something more meaningful or shorter using the IDE Property Editor.

**IF the dgv is on the current form**, the way to create a shorter reference is:

```
Dim dgv As DataGridView = Me.DataGridView1
```

If the control **is on a different existing form<sup>1</sup>**:

```
Dim dgv As DataGridView = theOtherFrmRef.DataGridView1
```

Finally, if you *are* trying to populate the DGV on a **new form instance**, be sure to `Show()` it at the end.

**`New`** creates a new instance of whatever and you do not need a new Form ref or a new DGV at all.  Assuming there are columns already added to the DGV, adding rows can also be simplified to:

```
dgv.Rows.Add(testCaseID, testCaseName)
```

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Also assumes explicit form instances.  Otherwise you might not be posting to the instance you think you are.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! arrgh such a simple mistake had me banging my head against a wall. I very much appreciate your answer